# Go equivalent of Python's Dictionary

Tags: go

I am looking for a way to store multiple values for each key (just like we can in python using dictionary) using Go.
Is there a way this can be achieved in Go?

Comment: What types of values are you trying to store?

Comment: key type : is an integer and value would be an array of something like ''map[name:1954]''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your response in comments I would suggest something like the following using a struct (though if you are only interested in a single value like `name` for each item in your slice then you could just use a `map[int][]string{}`

```
type Thing struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

myMap := map[int][]Thing{}
```

If you want to add things then you just do...

```
myMap[100] = append(myMap[100], Thing{"sberry": 37})
```

Or if you want to create it in place:

```
myMap := map[int][]Thing{
        100: []Thing{Thing{"sberry", 37}},
        2:   []Thing{Thing{"johndoe", 22}},
    }
```

**EDIT:** Adding a "nameIn" function based on comments as demo:

```
func nameIn(things []Thing, name string) bool {
    for _, thing := range things {
        if thing.name == name {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

if nameIn(myMap[100], "John") {
    ...
```

If the slices are really big and speed is  concern then you could keep a reverse lookup map like `map[string]int` where an entry would be `John: 100`, but you will need to most likely use some user defined functions to do your map modifications so it can change the reverse lookup as well.  This also limits you by requiring unique names.

Most likely the `nameIn` would work just fine.

Comment: You raise a good point. I wonder if by "multiple values" he means "multiple fields" and a `map[int]*Thing` would suffice.

Comment: nvm. read comment again. looks like he probably wants a slice of structs. maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on legacy data which is in a pretty bad shape. So what I am trying to do here is something like : myMap[100]={map["john":42],map["Alice":32],map["Fred":19]}. It's weird the way in which I have to deal with this data.

Comment: A `map` doesn't really make sense as your value since you won't ever know the keys and will need to iterate the key, value pair even though there is only a single entry.  A struct makes much more sense here.

Comment: The 'map[    ]'  thing is creating hurdles for me to access data like John:42. Any means by which I can make life better for myself? It would be ideal if I can do something like ' Does John belong to myMap[100]'?

Comment: Thank you all! @sberry Yes I did!

Answer (score 5):

In go, the key/value collection is called a `map`. You create it with `myMap := map[keyType]valType{}`

Usually something like `mapA := map[string]int{}`. If you want to store multiple values per key, perhaps something like:

`mapB := map[string][]string{}` where each element is itself a slice of strings. You can then add members with something like:

`mapB["foo"] = append(mapB["foo"], "fizzbuzz")`

For a great read see [Go maps in action](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

Comment: Thanks. That was useful!